# How do I get number of methods created from method template

Tags: c++, templates

Here's example code

```
tempalte<typename T>
void testFunc() {
    //Do something
}

int main(){
    int count = getNumberOfMethods(testFunc); //Point of interest
    
    testFunc<float>();
    testFunc<int>();
    testFunc<float>();
}
```

In this code we have a test template function, and in the main we call it with two different types (float and int), meaning that at compile time two functions are created from template.

Is there any way to find how many functions were created from template (in example code that is what point of interest is). For this example code, variable "count" should be 2 as we only create two functions out of template.

If I were to add `testFunc<byte>()` this would become 3 and so on.

One very important thing is that I need that count BEFORE I call the function, and that should be theoretically possible as functions are created at compile time.

In case you are wondering - I am trying to make entity component system (not because existing solutions are bad, but because I want to make my own) and it would be a huge optimization boost if I knew how many types of components exist throughout the code.

Comment: If you're asking "Can I reflect on all instances of a function created via a template" the short answer is "No". If you're using a template *class* then you might be able to do this with a lot of extra work.

Comment: Remember, template functions are compiled if/when they are used, and that is usually tracked *per compiled file*, not per application. I'm not sure the linker has enough information to extract this, though you could try and pull debug symbols and guess if you know how to get that information reliably. This would have to be done in a post-compilation pass, so to get a function like that to work you'd have to build at least twice.

Comment: This reads a bit like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806), because you're describing a desire to circumvent the language to solve your perceived problem, instead of describing the actual requirements and seeking advice on standard solutions.  A "normal" approach to this kind of thing would involve all your "entities" being registered with some sort of manager up-front when the program is initialized.

Comment: It is **impossible** to count the number of templatized functions *before* it's being called.